# I cant able to get the value from one page to another...give me some ideas

Tags: php

I can't able to get the values from one page to another in PHP

This is the code

```
<form action="example/registered.php" method="post">
  <h3>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="FirstName" size="75" height= "100px" width= "100px" value="suba">
  <br><br>

  <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="LastName" size="75" height= "100px" width= "100px" value="Krishnan">
  </h3>
  <br><br>

  <h5> <a class="link" href="{{ url('registered') }}">Register</a> </h5>

</form>
```

Comment: You can learn how to handle Form with PHP here: [PHP 5 Form Handling](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

Comment: Try learning about Session variables in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

(Somewhat ignoring this template-looking code which presumably generates a URL, since there's no information about it in the question...)  This is just a link:

```
<a class="link" href="{{ url('registered') }}">Register</a>
```

A link doesn't submit a form.  A submit button does.  Replace your link with a submit button to post your form to the form's action URL:

```
<input type="submit" class="link" value="Register" />
```

Comment: Even though, i don't get it

Comment: @SubaKrishnan: Can you elaborate on that?  What specifically isn't working?

Comment: Hey, i got it...tnq